# EmptyStackException error with Stack in Java

Tags: java, stack

What I'm trying to do is to get the eval variable to have each of its letters put into a stack and then printed out. I'm getting an EmptyStackException error(assuming that means that there isn't anything in the stack). What I don't understand is that I thought that the eval string was put into the variable stack. Why is it empty?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

   Stack<String> variable = new Stack<String>();

   String eval = StdIn.readString();
   String alphabet = "abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";


   for (int i = 0; i < eval.length(); i++)
   {
       eval = eval.substring(i,i);

       if (eval.equals(alphabet.substring(0, 52)))// checks if eval is equal to any letter of alphabet
     {
           variable.push(eval);

       System.out.println(variable.pop());
     }
   } 
  }
}
```

Im using eclipse

---

Sample Runs:

```
input: hello
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
at java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Stack.pop(Unknown Source)
at eval.main(eval.java:31)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few issues I can see:

1. `eval.substring(i,i);` will return an empty string every time. You want `eval.substring(i,i + 1);`, or even better, `eval.charAt(i);`.
2. You'll want to put the returned substring/charAt character in it's own variable within your `for` loop. Currently it is overriding the `eval` string after the first iteration.
3. `if (eval.equals(alphabet.substring(0, 52)))` doesn't do what you seem to think it does judging by your comment. If you want to check if a string contains another string (or even just a single character), use the methods: `String#contains` or `String#indexOf`.

---

Here's a simple corrected snippet:

```
    String alphabet = "abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String eval = "blah";
    Stack<Character> chars = new Stack<Character>();

    for(char c : eval.toCharArray()) {
        if(alphabet.indexOf(c) != -1) {
            chars.push(c);
            System.out.println(chars.pop());
        }
    }
```

Comment: See, I wanted to use eval.CharAt(i), but it said that I couldn't convert a string into a char.

Comment: Using eval.substring(i, i+1) will satisfy this requirement.

Comment: @igknighton I have provided an example for you.

Comment: @igknighton - Please read the answer properly.  It gives you all of the information needed to understand why your program is failing.

Answer (score 6):

The only way that you are getting this error is if:

```
for (int i = 0; i < eval.length(); i++)
   {
       eval = eval.substring(i,i);

       if (eval.equals(alphabet.substring(0, 52)))
     {
           variable.push(eval);


     }
 System.out.println(variable.pop());
   }
```

If you have the  `System.out.println(variable.pop());` outside of the if condition.

**[pop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#push%28java.lang.Object%29)**

```
public Object pop()
```

> Removes the object at the top of this stack and returns that object as
>   the value of this function.
>
> Returns: The object at the top of this stack (the last item of the
>   Vector object). Throws:

**EmptyStackException** - if this stack is empty.

In the code that you posted this is not possible since you have the same number of `push` and `pop`, and the `push` operation comes first than `pop`.

**The code you have put**:

[image]

**the error you are getting**:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to check that each letter in `eval` is a letter before you push it onto the stack.  After you go through all characters in `eval`, pop everything off the stack and print it out.

```
for(int i = 0; i < eval.length(); i++) {

    if(alphabet.contains(eval.charAt(i))) {

        variable.push(eval.charAt(i));
    }
}

while(!variable.isEmpty()) {

    System.out.println(variable.pop());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to check whether the characters in a string read from input are letters, and put them in a stac
You should consider using the [Character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) which let you perform all sort of tests on characters, without having to worry about encoding. The method that might be useful in your case is `isLetter`, which check if the character is a letter.

As for the stack issue, your code actually push a value on top of the stack, and then immediately `pop` it of, which explains why your stack is empty at the end of the loop. You should use the `peek` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should resolve your issue:
You should only be popping after you push. Thus, they should both be inside the if-statement.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < eval.length(); i++)
    {
       if (alphabet.contains(eval.substring(i,i+1))
       {
           variable.push(eval.substring(i,i+1));
           System.out.println(variable.pop());
       }
     }
```